# Upgrading to Angular 7 Ecma6 not working why?

Tags: angular, angular7, ecmascript-2017

i just updated my application from angular 6 to angular 7 but some sort of which was working in angular 6 not working in angular 7 it puts browser in infinite loading.

For eg:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-page',
   template: `<div *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(items)">{{key + ' : ' + 
   items[key]}}</div>`
})

export class MyComponent {
   objectKeys = Object.keys;
   items = { keyOne: 'value 1', keyTwo: 'value 2', keyThree: 'value 3' };
   constructor(){}
}
```

This above code was working in angular 6 but not in angular 7 why is that so?
Sorry for my English, hope anyone can help me out or makeme understand wht wrong happned?

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Comment: @user1664823 not error message showing just browser tab freezes

Comment: I'm not sure why your browser freezes but in your example you could use the [keyvalue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe). `<div *ngFor="let item of items | keyvalue">{{item.key}} : {{item.value}}</div>`

Comment: @fridoo thank you, but my question is for why Ecma6 script which was working in angular 6 now not working in angular 7?

Comment: I don't see this issue.  I have included a stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9n6gqr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts).  Please see answer below about targeting ES6 in typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set the tsconfig.json file to target ES6?

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es6"   
}
}
```

Comment: Yes my tsconfig.json has target value set properly, may be i have to see my configuration again what mistake is done while migrating.